# Obtener un valor por defecto en un select mvc 5

Tags: asp.net, mvc

He creado una vista parcial en el cual un objeto `<select></select>` es llenado desde una base de datos **sql server** mediante un `for each`. los valores que toman por ejm son:

> 1 Articulos de limpieza
>
> 2 Articulos de ferreteria
>
> 3 Frutas y Verduras...etc

Hasta ahí esta todo bien, pero cuando creo otra vista y llamo a este `select` no puedo ponerle un valor por defecto...La vista que he creado trae los datos de un articulo como su código, nombre, precio y tipo de articulo (que aparecen en la lista `select`)...Necesito que cuando llame a un articulo el tipo al que pertenece se seleccione de esta lista automáticamente
este es el codigo con el cual llamo a la lista

```
@Html.Action("BuscarArticuloLinea", "ArticuloLinea", New With 
{.htmlAttributes = New With {.value = IdArticuloLinea}})
```

Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Hola, realiza las ediciones en tu pregunta, mediante el enlace [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/123158/edit).

Answer (score -1):

Puedes incluir el atributo html `selected` al elemento que quieras por defecto.

```
<option selected="selected">
 3
</option>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, sin embargo esto no responde a la pregunta, también te sugiero revisar [answer], saludos!.

Comment: no estoy de acuerdo, porque claramente está usando el .htmlAttributes, por lo tanto lo unico que tiene que hacer es agregar el atributo selected para lograr lo que estoy mostrando en el trozo de código, no entiendo por qué además le restan votos si la respuesta es correcta, no veo como no se entiende que tiene que agregar .htmlAttributes = New With {.value = "selected"}